# Как изменить данные в getters, не изменяя state

Tags: vue.js, vuex

Всем привет. Хочу с помощью getter получить данные из state и их изменить, но так чтобы данные в самом state не поменялись. Как правильно это делать?

```
state: {
  loraServer: null
},
getters: {
// Скрывает секретные данные сервера из геттера - не работает - заменяет данные в state
loraServerSecured: (state) => {
  let hide = state.loraServer
  if (hide) {
    state.loraServer.forEach(function (item) {
      item.user = '_user'
      item.password = '_password'
     })
  }
  return hide
}
```

Использование Object.assign(state.loraServer) так же не помогло.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Геттеры для того и нужны, чтобы возвращать измененную информацию. Только вместо [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach), правильнее использовать [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

Создадим дубликат массива объектов с необходимым набором свойств:

```
// ex.: store.js

state: {
  loraServer: []
},

getters: {
  loraServerSecured: state => {
    return state.loraServer
      .map(function(item) {
        return {
          ...item,
          user: '_user',
          password: '_password'
        }
      })
  }
}
```

Comment: спасибо, ваше решение более правильное.

Answer (score 0):

Работает так (глубокое клонирование)

```
getters: {
// Скрывает секретные данные сервера из геттера - не работает - заменяет данные в state
secureLoraServer: (state) => {
  let hide = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(state.loraServer))
  if (hide) {
    hide.forEach(function (item) {
      console.log('forEach')
      item.user = '_user'
      item.password = '_password'
    })
  }
  return hide
}
```